# elements in ui not reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make reactive elements in my shiny app using RStudio. I want the radio buttons to appear or disappear depending upon a checkbox. Then I am gathering the inputs from the elements displayed to generate two graphs. The problem is that the elements in UI are not reactive. Below is the coding I used.

```
library(shiny)
library(AER)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


CreditCard <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3ffc253260bae6894c00edb2062729d6/raw/6c08d02eaba4b1691212fd518f2079ef2c112a20/Credit_Card.csv")
key <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a8c05eb2202d79b03b187117e6fe709/raw/beddca49b669fe5ff27ce7dd1c7bcbe1c4660327/key.csv")


df_cc = CreditCard[sample(nrow(CreditCard), 500), ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Final Project",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(
        'input.tabs === "Graphs"',


        checkboxInput("checkbox_facet", label = "Show Facet", value = TRUE),
        tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),

        selectInput("select_y", label = h4("Select Y-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "active"),

        selectInput("select_x", label = h4("Select X-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "income")
      ) # end conditionalPanel for graphs 



    ), #end sidebarPanel


    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabs',

        tabPanel("Graphs", 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "exp"), 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "reg"), 
                 uiOutput(outputId = "facet")
        ) #Graphs

      ) # end tabsetPanel
    ) # end mainPanel
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {


  observeEvent(input$checkbox_facet, { if (input$checkbox_facet == TRUE) { # radio buttons for facet options show, and graph be made accordingly.
    output$facet <- eventReactive(input$checkbox_facet, { insertUI( selector = "#placeholder",
                                                                 ui = radioButtons("radio_facet", label = h4("Choose Facet Variable"),
                                                                                   choices = list("Card" = "card", "Reports" = "reports", "Owner" = "owner", "SelfEmployed" = "selfemp", "Dependents" = "dependents"), selected = "owner")
    ) })

    output$exp <- eventReactive(input$select_x, { renderPlotly({ 
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) + geom_point(shape=1) + 
          facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both) +
          labs(title = "Exploratory Plot", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)
      )
    })
    })
    output$reg <- eventReactive(input$select_x, { renderPlotly({ 
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) + geom_point(shape=1) + 
          geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "poisson", se = FALSE) +
          facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both) +
          labs(title = "Poisson Regression", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)
      )
    })
    })

  }
    else { # radio buttons disappear and graph is without facets
      output$facet <- eventReactive(input$checkbox_facet, { removeUI(selector = 'div:has(> #radio_facet)', immediate = TRUE) })
      output$exp <- eventReactive(input$select_x, { renderPlotly({ 
        ggplotly(
          ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) + geom_point(shape=1) +
            labs(title = "Exploratory Plot", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)
        )
      })
      })
      output$reg <- eventReactive(input$select_x, { renderPlotly({ 
        ggplotly(
          ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) + geom_point(shape=1) + 
            geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "poisson", se = FALSE) +
            labs(title = "Poisson Regression", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)
        )
      })
      })
    } 
  }) # end observeEvent for graphs



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Take a look at `conditionalPanel`

Comment: @ Gregor de Cillia what about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just overcomplicating things.

In your code, you have reactive expressions, that reactively assign other reactive expressions. So you always fight with a double layer of reactivity.

I don't know if you noticed, but you also delete the placeholder div the first time the checkbox is unchecked. You maybe did this on purpose, because otherwise the radio buttons will always be there. Because overwriting the `output$facet` will not delete any reacting expressions. And your reactive logic itself does not contain the state of `input$checkbox_facet`. So you are always fighting with reactive expressions, that you reassign and where you have no control over how they are executed.

What I recommend is, to clean up your code. Pick each output element by itself and define what reactions you really want to happen. And then define a fixed behaviour, that reflects that.

Also, be aware that render functions are reactive environments by default.

Below is a refactoring that works:

```
library(shiny)
library(AER)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


CreditCard <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3ffc253260bae6894c00edb2062729d6/raw/6c08d02eaba4b1691212fd518f2079ef2c112a20/Credit_Card.csv")
key <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a8c05eb2202d79b03b187117e6fe709/raw/beddca49b669fe5ff27ce7dd1c7bcbe1c4660327/key.csv")


df_cc = CreditCard[sample(nrow(CreditCard), 500), ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Final Project",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(
        'input.tabs === "Graphs"',


        checkboxInput("checkbox_facet", label = "Show Facet", value = TRUE),
        uiOutput("facets"),

        selectInput("select_y", label = h4("Select Y-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "active"),

        selectInput("select_x", label = h4("Select X-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "income")
      ) # end conditionalPanel for graphs 



    ), #end sidebarPanel


    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabs',

        tabPanel("Graphs", 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "exp"), 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "reg")
        ) #Graphs

      ) # end tabsetPanel
    ) # end mainPanel
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$facets <- renderUI({
    if (input$checkbox_facet) {
      radioButtons("radio_facet",
        label = h4("Choose Facet Variable"),
        choices = list("Card" = "card", "Reports" = "reports", "Owner" = "owner", "SelfEmployed" = "selfemp", "Dependents" = "dependents"),
        selected = "owner"
      )
    }
  })

  output$exp <- renderPlotly({ 
    g <- ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      labs(title = "Exploratory Plot", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)

    if (input$checkbox_facet) {
      g <- g + facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both)
    }

    ggplotly(g)
  })

  output$reg <- renderPlotly({ 
    g <- ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "poisson", se = FALSE) +
      labs(title = "Poisson Regression", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)

    if (input$checkbox_facet) {
      g <- g + facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both)
    }

    ggplotly(g)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To address the comment from *Gregor de Cillia* about conditional panels: You might not want to recreate the radio buttons every time the checkbox changes, since the options are in fact always the same. (And you might want to keep the state, i.e. which item was selected previously.) A `conditionalPanel` just hides the radio buttons and therefore cleans up your `server` code even more.

Example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(AER)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


CreditCard <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3ffc253260bae6894c00edb2062729d6/raw/6c08d02eaba4b1691212fd518f2079ef2c112a20/Credit_Card.csv")
key <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a8c05eb2202d79b03b187117e6fe709/raw/beddca49b669fe5ff27ce7dd1c7bcbe1c4660327/key.csv")


df_cc = CreditCard[sample(nrow(CreditCard), 500), ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Final Project",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(
        'input.tabs === "Graphs"',


        checkboxInput("checkbox_facet", label = "Show Facet", value = TRUE),
        conditionalPanel('input.checkbox_facet',
          radioButtons("radio_facet",
                       label = h4("Choose Facet Variable"),
                       choices = list("Card" = "card", "Reports" = "reports", "Owner" = "owner", "SelfEmployed" = "selfemp", "Dependents" = "dependents"),
                       selected = "owner"
          )
        ),

        selectInput("select_y", label = h4("Select Y-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "active"),

        selectInput("select_x", label = h4("Select X-Axis"), 
                    choices = list("Age" = "age", "Income" = "income", "Share" = "share", "Expenditure" = "expenditure", "Months" = "months", "MajorCards" = "majorcards", "Active" = "active"), selected = "income")
      ) # end conditionalPanel for graphs 



    ), #end sidebarPanel


    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabs',

        tabPanel("Graphs", 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "exp"), 
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "reg")
        ) #Graphs

      ) # end tabsetPanel
    ) # end mainPanel
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$exp <- renderPlotly({ 
    g <- ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      labs(title = "Exploratory Plot", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)

    if (input$checkbox_facet) {
      g <- g + facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both)
    }

    ggplotly(g)
  })

  output$reg <- renderPlotly({ 
    g <- ggplot(df_cc, aes(x=get(input$select_x), y=get(input$select_y))) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = "poisson", se = FALSE) +
      labs(title = "Poisson Regression", x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y)

    if (input$checkbox_facet) {
      g <- g + facet_wrap(~get(input$radio_facet), labeller = label_both)
    }

    ggplotly(g)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get it now :)

Comment: @ K. Rohde Can you also please tell me how to label the facets so that they don't show as `input$...`.  `labeller` parameter takes only fixed set arguments. How can I change that to my preferred one?

Comment: @Jay This you could have researched well on your own. `facet_wrap` does not only take formulas but also simple character vectors as first input. Try `facet_wrap(input$radio_facet, ...)` to get the original column name. Other than that, `labeller` takes function arguments which you can shape to return the custom label you want.